# Transaction hash is 'undefined' when running web3 code from command prompt

Tags: web3js, transactions

I wrote this java script code to send test ether to my other account:

```
var Tx = require('ethereumjs-tx').Transaction
var Web3 = require('web3')
web3 = new Web3('https://ropsten.infura.io/hqRzEqFKv6IsjRxfVUMH')
const account1 = '0x0539B9c9C886e93778542B553C64cb5EAfB902b1'
const account2 = '0xca7F442c44b079dd07324C9c7eDfe348b92f46c9'
const privatekey1 = Buffer.from('cxxxxxxxxxxxxx5xd0804xxxxxxx238ca1aed1xxx' , 'hex')
web3.eth.getTransactionCount(account1 , (err, transCount) => {
const txObject = {
nonce: web3.utils.toHex(transCount) ,
to: account2 ,
value: web3.utils.toHex(web3.utils.toWei('1' , 'ether')) ,
gasLimit: web3.utils.toHex(30000) ,
gasPrice: web3.utils.toHex(web3.utils.toWei('10' , 'gwei'))
}
var tx = new Tx(txObject)
tx.sign(privatekey1)
const serializedTransaction = tx.serialize()
const raw = '0x' + serializedTransaction.toString('hex')
web3.eth.sendSignedTransaction(raw , (err, txHash) => 
  {console.log('txHash: ' , txHash)})
})
```

Now I run this code in the command prompt:

```
C:\Users\HP\path>
node testEther
```

This outputs:

```
txHash: undefined
```

> txHash: undefined

Why does this happen? I have tried to connect to different ropsten network, but still the problem persists. I have checked my test ether balance and it shows that I have enough ether.The transaction does not happen at all. Is the way I am connecting to ropsten wrong?

Comment: What version of web3.js are you using?

Comment: version: 12.13.0

Comment: There's no such version of web3.js. The major version is either 0 or 1. There is an alpha for 2 as well, but I doubt you're using it. Please run `npm ls web3` from a command line and come back with the result. Alternatively, you can `console.log(web3.version)` from your JS code.

Comment: In any case, since you print the second parameter and get `undefined`, try to print the first parameter (called `err` in your code). I have a guts feeling that you'll be surprised of what you find in there (which ain't gonna be an error object as you might expect).

Comment: Sorry, I entered node.js version. Web3 version is 1.2.4

Comment: I tried console.log(err), but the same thing happened. It still says undefined..

Comment: Maybe instead of using the callback-function parameter, try the `on`-scheme, as shown in [this coding example](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.2.4/web3-eth.html#id76) (which is for `sendTransaction`, but I believe that it should work the same for `sendSignedTransaction`).

Comment: The Infura URL you are using is old and deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

Where you have

```
var tx = new Tx(txObject)
```

you need

```
const tx = new Tx(txObject, {chain:'ropsten', hardfork: 'petersburg'})
```

h/t

https://community.infura.io/t/sendsignedtransaction-invalid-sender-error/832

**Full Code**

This code is working locally. Replace your infura url and private key.

- web3 1.2.4
- ethereumjs-tx 2.1.1 (installed with separate `npm install ethereumjs-tx`)

```
var Tx = require('ethereumjs-tx').Transaction
var Web3 = require('web3');
var web3 = new Web3('https://ropsten.infura.io/v3/INFURA_PROJECT');
const account1 = '0x926f8E72CE94491Cafba874b4affD40C3b05a5e3'
const account2 = '0xca7F442c44b079dd07324C9c7eDfe348b92f46c9'
const privatekey1 = Buffer.from('PRIVATE_KEY' , 'hex')
web3.eth.getTransactionCount(account1 , (err, transCount) => {
  const txObject = {
    nonce: web3.utils.toHex(transCount) ,
    from: account1,
    to: account2 ,
    value: web3.utils.toHex(web3.utils.toWei('.01' , 'ether')) ,
    gasLimit: web3.utils.toHex(30000) ,
    gasPrice: web3.utils.toHex(web3.utils.toWei('10' , 'gwei'))
  }
  const tx = new Tx(txObject, {chain:'ropsten', hardfork: 'petersburg'})
  tx.sign(privatekey1)
  const serializedTransaction = tx.serialize()
  const raw = '0x' + serializedTransaction.toString('hex')
  web3.eth.sendSignedTransaction(raw , (err, txHash) => {
    console.log('txHash: ' , txHash)
  });
});
```

A resulting transaction:

https://ropsten.etherscan.io/tx/0x2b2f2a09d7d9d7cf8ec7243c6975b14d1db04ebaa2cff530700cf686d88095e9

Comment: Tried it but still got the same result.

Comment: Try also adding a from in the transaction (from: account 1) before the to

Comment: Also maybe try a more simple action like getBalance instead of sending a transaction to confirm your web3/provider is connected w/o and error